# JUnit testing of OutputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, outputstream

I am trying to write a test for the writeMessage() method. But I have no idea how to start, since I need to test an OutputStream. This should be something like a small chat. It should read a message from console, write it to the text file and than print all messages that have been written to the file.

This is for a university project.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ChatIntImplement implements ChatI {

    public static String readMessage() throws IOException, NullPointerException{
        InputStream is = System.in;
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message = null;

        try {
            message = br.readLine();

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("couldn't write data (fatal)");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return message;
    }

    public static void messageToFile(String message) throws IOException {
        try {
        String filename = "savedMessage.txt";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
        ps.println(message);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("couldn't open file - fatal");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void showMessages() {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
        is = new FileInputStream("savedMessage.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message;
        while((message = br.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("couln't open file -fatal");
            System.exit(0);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("couldn't read data (fatal)");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void writeMessage(String message){
        try {
        messageToFile(message);
        showMessages();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("couldn't write data (fatal");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatIntImplement chat = new ChatIntImplement();
        try {
        String message = readMessage();
        chat.writeMessage(message);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("couldn't write data (fatal");
            System.exit(0);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.err.println("Du hast nichts eingegeben");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }


    }
```

Comment: See https://www.journaldev.com/878/java-write-to-file

Comment: What is it what you want to test? Remember, you shouldn't test the Java API, it has already been tested, so you're not testing whether `FileOutputStream` works, so what exactly is it that you want/need to test? If you're going to write code with unit tests, you need to write the code in "units", so you can test the "unit". What "unit" functionality are you trying to test here?

Comment: *FYI:* The `messageToFile` method has failed visual testing, since we can *see* that it doesn't work right, given that it doesn't close the `FileOutputStream`. But then, we wouldn't need unit testing to tell us that, since any **good IDE** would have already warned us about that when we wrote the code.

Comment: @FailingCoder *"You have to create a file before you can output to it."* Huh? `new FileOutputStream(filename, true)` creates the file, for output. You don't have to create the file first.

Comment: The thing is, that I should write the tests before I even implement the methods.(requeirement of our prof.) So its not important if the method is working correctly or not I just need to write a test for it.
I want to test the method writemessage(). Imagine that we dont have the implementation. It should be like a blackbox test. The method should get a String and write it to the .txt file and than display all messages in console.

Comment: I am a beginner so i might not understand some basic stuff. But why is the code failing your visual test? if i run it in my IDE, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having getting started is because of how you have structured your class. All of your methods are static, and each method's dependencies, such as the various input and output streams you are using, are created as needed inside each method. For instance, in your messageToFile(...) method:

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
```

A much better approach to your project would be design your class using a traditional object-oriented class design that makes use of a pattern called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

The idea here is that your class that implements your ChatI interface would use member-variables for your input and output streams and the other objects, which would be initialized in the constructor for the class. Then you could control, and most importantly, get access to those streams from within your unit tests - something like this perhaps:

```
    @Test
    public void givenAMessageString_When() {
      String expectedInput="expectedString";
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ChatIntImplement chat = new ChatIntImplement(baos);
      ...
      chat.writeMessage(expectedInput);
      string output = new String(baos.toByteArray());
      assertThat(output).equals(expectedInput);
    }
```